# How do I translate quicktab headings?

Tags: i18n-l10n, blocks

I am a newcomer to Drupal. I am developing a website with multilingual support and I have translated most of the contents, blocks etc. but wasn't able to translate the Quicktab tab title.

I am using i18n, languageicons and languagedropdown modules for this purpose. How do I translate Quicktab tab title?

Comment: Each Quicktabs instance has a corresponding block that is managed on the blocks administration page. If you click on the `configure` link next to that block and choose `Languages` under `Visibility settings`, you have an option there to allow translations. I don't know how to actually do the translations, but maybe this can get you one step closer...

Comment: Have you tried with LOCALE module **translate interface**(admin/config/regional/translate/translate)?

Answer (score 3):

1. Ensure you have downloaded (if needed) and enabled the 'Locale', ['Internationalization'](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n), 'String translation' modules
2. Go to Configurations > Translate Interface > Strings (Tab) (`admin/config/regional/translate/i18n_string`)
3. Check the 'Quicktabs' checkbox under the 'Select text groups' heading, and click 'Refresh strings'
4. Go to the page where it the quick tabs is and refresh it a few times (normally, you **WOULDN'T** need to do this, but for me, if I didn't and it's not cached, it doesn't work)
5. Go back to Configuration > Translate Interface > Translate (Tab) (`admin/config/regional/translate/translate`) , and search, using the 'String contains' input box, for ***one of the tab titles***. I.e. if your tab titles are 'Apples', 'Oranges' and 'Pears', search for 'Apples'.
6. You should be able to see an entry. Click 'edit' and translate away!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7, you can achieve it by using **LOCALE module**

Steps

- After installing and configuring **Locale module** go to *admin/config/regional/translate/translate*
- Search for your **TAB heading** by clicking **FILTER** button and translate it to your corresponding language by editing it.

  [image]

  [image]

Note :

If the TAB heading is render using t() function, then only you can able to find the string and translate it.